# Redirect to a specific subfolder using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, subdirectory

Here's my folder structure:

- website.com

  - main

    - sub1
    - sub2

I would like to be able to access the subfolder `sub1` via the URL `website.com/sub1`, which I managed to do so by adding the following in my `.htaccess` under `website/` :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /sub1/(.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*)$ main/sub1/index.php?view=$1 [QSA,L]
```

My problem is that although the `index.php` is accessed, it is accessed all the time, even for the `.js` and `.css` files. So I tried to add the following rule before (although I though I excluded the files via my `!-f` condition before):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /sub1/(.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ main/sub1/$1 [L,QSA]
```

But as you can guess, no luck, no actual files ever go into that second block even when I delete the other one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/sub1/(.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/main/%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /main/$1 [L]
```

then your old rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /sub1/(.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*)$ main/sub1/index.php?view=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly! I can even re-use it for additionnal subfolders I have in `main`; I tested and I just had to do a few tweaks in my "old rules" to make it work. I think yout DOCUMENT_ROOT and /main/ idea was brilliant.